# looping a function that calls apply throwing error

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape tables from multiple pages. Have written a function that takes a list of urls:

```
head(url2)
[1] "http://www.fake URL1/WordDocuments.htm"
[2] "http://www.fake URL2/WordDocuments.htm"
[3] "http://www.fake URL3/WordDocuments.htm"                 
[5] "http://www.fake URL4/WordDocumentS.htm"            
[6] "http://www.fake URL5/WordDocuments.htm"
```

where this function scrapes what I want for a given url number from `url2`:

```
scrapePage <- function(a,i){

p2<-htmlParse(a[i])
tableNodes = getNodeSet(p2, "//table")
raw.tables<-readHTMLTable(p2, which = 6:length(tableNodes))
parsed.tables<-lapply(raw.tables,function(x) as.data.frame(apply(x,2,function(y) gsub("\\s+", " ", y))))
return(parsed.tables)

}
```

so if I call `scrapePage(url2,5)` I get the required tables from the 5th url.

I now want to loop this. Naturally I tried:

```
parsed.pages<-list()
for (i in 1:length(url2)){
  parsed.pages<-scrapePage(url2,i)
}
```

but this gives me:

```
 Error in apply(x, 2, function(y) gsub("\\s+", " ", y)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Does anyone see what I have done wrong here?

Comment: Try with `parsed.pages[i] <- scrapePage(url2,i)`

Comment: same error sorry @Pascal, although I generate warnings doing this (which I have included in my post

Comment: `scrapePage(url2,i)` works for all `i`? ( try to find`i`   where it fails( see i value when error ) and make step by step througth your function)

Comment: OK. That will solve a future problem. For which URL do you get the error?

Comment: HI both - this a is a good suggestion - I know that the urls for `head(url2)` all work with my function. so I passed only these into the for loop `for (i in 1:length(head(url2))){}` but still get the same error plus warnings

Comment: I have even tried just passing the first two urls which I know work. Still the same result however. I do not think it is an issue with the individual urls

Comment: eventually dropped dimensions? However: it is time for debugging.

Comment: dropping the lapply() line in my function allows it to run just fine, however I never get to use the gsub command to remove multiple whitespaces. That is the offending line anyway

Answer (score 0):

Trying the following example, I get the same error:

```
apply(NULL, 2, function(x) sum)
apply(numeric(0), 2, function(x) sum) #or similar
```

So I guess one of your links does not work properly and does not contain an object (here x) with a length greater 0.
I would add a

```
print(paste0("Processing: ", i, " of ", length(url2)))
```

to check which item it is.
Further more you could at a if condition to check the length of the data.frame you expect and if it's length/nrow is 0 set some NA value. EDIT: Mention that the input `a` into `scrapePage` is now `url2[1]`, `url2[2]`, ...

```
scrapePage <- function(a, verbose = 0){
  if (verbose > 0) print(a)
  p2<-htmlParse(a)
  tableNodes = getNodeSet(p2, "//table")
  raw.tables<-readHTMLTable(p2, which = 6:length(tableNodes))
  parsed.tables<-lapply(raw.tables,function(x){
    if (length(x)>0){
      as.data.frame(apply(x,2,function(y) gsub("\\s+", " ", y)))
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  })
  return(parsed.tables)
 }
```

I added a if-condition to the inner function right before the apply to check for the length of x. If the length is larger than 0 (positive length) it should work, in the other case NA is returned (you can of course switch to any other result like 0, NULL or similar).
Further more you can use the parameter verbose to print the processed file.
By the way, you can shorten the for loop to:

```
parsed.pages <- lapply(url2, scrapePage, verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing inside the function's loop the `lapply()` with `sapply()` to remove multiple whitespaces:

```
parsed.tables <- data.frame(sapply(raw.tables, function(x) gsub("\\s+", " ", x)))
```

Comment: To OP - any questions or issues in implementing above answer?